# How to solve "Operands ... must be convertible to logical scalar values" MATLAB error message?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, syntax-error

I always get this error message when I run my code in MATLAB. I want to do template matching to recognise a character.

```
  ??? Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.

  Error in ==> readLetter at 17
  if vd==1 || vd==2
```

My code is

```
  load NewTemplates % Loads the templates of characters in the memory.
  gambar = imresize(gambar,[42 24]); % Resize the input image 
  comp = [];
  for n = 1 : length(NewTemplates)
      sem = corr2(NewTemplates{1,n}, gambar); % Correlation with every image in the template for best matching.
      comp = [comp sem]; % Record the value of correlation for each template's character.
  end

  vd = find(comp == max(comp)); % Find index of highest matched character.

  % According to the index assign to 'letter'.
  if vd==1 || vd==2
      letter='A';
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Use `[~,vd]=max(comp)` if you want the index of the max value at comp.

Comment: When i add the code to [~,vd]=find(comp==max(comp)); there are a error messege "??? Error: File: readLetter.m Line: 13 Column: 3
Expression or statement is incorrect--possibly unbalanced (, {, or [.".

Comment: You didn't understand. You don't need the find to get the index, you can obtain it directly using the max function, writing `[maxv,maxind]=max(comp)`, where `maxv` is the max value and `maxind` is the max value index.

Answer (score 1):

find() returns a vector when comp contains multiple elements with the maximum value.

See this:

```
a = [1:5 5];
index = find(a==max(a)); % index =  5  6
numel(index) % ans = 2
```

So use either the max function **instead of find** or use only the first match.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have non-scalar values returned in `vd` (i.e., many locations for the same maximum value). Thus your comparing of vectors, element-wise, in the `if` statement generates the error.

If you want the multiple maxima behaviour (which doesn't make much sense unless you want to check for a vector of `1`s) you can use the `|` operator instead

```
r = randi(2,10,1);
vd = find(r==max(r));

if vd==1 | vd==2
    letter='A';
end
```

If not, try picking a single value from `vd` (i.e. first instance `vd(1)` or a random instance as below) prior to checking it's value with the `if` statement:

```
vd = vd(randi(length(vd))); % random index from returned in vd
if vd==1 || vd==2
     letter='A';
end
```